# Angular directive with methods that are called from dynamic html

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a wrapper for a visual component using a directive. I want to achieve a level of abstraction where all code related to component's generic functionality will live in the directive. So my questions are: how to add methods to a directive and call them from within this directive? To make it more messy I am generating some dynamic html where I need to call these methods. Hope it's clear. Thanks for the help.

Adding code:

```
rismDirectives.directive('theDirective', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
       // function to call later
        scope.getFilteredAssets = function (filter) {
            ....
        }
```

................
When I click on an image that was added to component dynamically the getFilteredAssets actually gets called twice (somehow from not being called I got it getting called twice). I am calling it with a parameter that is undefined in the function. Also after clicking I see that a path to my current page in the address bar has been reverted to the main application page. So, if it was mainpage#/page1 then after clicking it becomes mainpage#.

Comment: You're basically asking how to create a directive. Read the manual. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom

Comment: No, I am not. I know how to create a directive. I am specifically asking how to add methods to it that can be called within this directive. I can add these methods to a controller but then I need to add the same methods to every controller that accompanies a view with my component.

Comment: And the link I gave you explains how to do it. Read it. Then try something. Then if you're stuck, post what you tried and ask a concrete question.

Comment: What's more trickier is to call these methods from a dynamic html that I am adding to a component at the runtime. HTML sample: "<div class="datagrid-cell datagrid-cell-c1-itemtype" style="text-align: left;"><span>Item Type</span><span class="datagrid-sort-icon">&nbsp;</span></div><a href="" ng-click="getFilteredAssets()"><img border="0" src="all_filter.png"></a> ... The click is not triggering getFilteredAssets().

Comment: That must be a problem with the code. But you didn't post any code. So we can't help.

Comment: That's better, but still incomplete. We don't know what the directive should do, not how it does it. Post the **complete** code, with a **complete** usage example. Explain precisely what the directive is supposed to do.